# Is there a way to remove the owner's read permissions on a file in macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, file-permissions, chmod, macos-big-sur

Is there any way to take away the owner's permission to read a file in macOS? I know there's no reason to do this but I have to for school and I can't find an answer anywhere. Removing my write permission works fine but when I try to remove my read permission it automatically give me my read and write permissions back. As you can see in the console when I use chmod -v -v (extra verbose) it shows the correct permissions it should be changed to but then when checking afterwards they havent changed into that...

```
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % ls -l
total 16
-rw----r--  1 thijs  staff  12 Oct 11 21:10 greeting.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 thijs  staff   0 Oct 11 21:10 hello.txt
-rw-------  1 thijs  staff  15 Oct 11 21:11 weather.txt
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % chmod -v -v u-w weather.txt 
weather.txt: 0100600 [-rw------- ] -> 0100400 [-r-------- ]
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % ls -l 
total 16
-rw----r--  1 thijs  staff  12 Oct 11 21:10 greeting.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 thijs  staff   0 Oct 11 21:10 hello.txt
-r--------  1 thijs  staff  15 Oct 11 21:11 weather.txt
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % chmod -v -v u-r weather.txt 
weather.txt: 0100400 [-r-------- ] -> 0100000 [---------- ]
thijs@Thijss-MacBook-Air-2 week6 % ls -l
total 16
-rw----r--  1 thijs  staff  12 Oct 11 21:10 greeting.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 thijs  staff   0 Oct 11 21:10 hello.txt
-rw-------  1 thijs  staff  15 Oct 11 21:11 weather.txt
```

Comment: This should have been posted at [askdifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or posted at [superuser](https://superuser.com/) because it's not likely to be *only* peculiar to macOS.